# .resx not working with vb code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am making an asp.net web application with vb coding behind. I found a code online for making a multilingual website, and as the original code is in C# I made a C# project to try it. Everything went fine. Now, I converted the code to VB to use it on the original project, and for some reason, the Debugging doesn't want to start, always throwing MissingManifestResourceException as an error. The resource files' Build Action is set to Embedded Resource, and the Code I am using is this:

```
Dim rm As ResourceManager
Dim ci As CultureInfo
Private Sub LoadString()
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo(Session("Lang").ToString())
    rm = New ResourceManager("WebApplication6.App_GlobalResources.Lang", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

    NavigationMenu.Items(0).Text = rm.GetString("MenuItemDefault", ci)
    NavigationMenu.Items(1).Text = rm.GetString("MenuItemAbout", ci)
End Sub
```

Where "Lang" is the name of the base Resource File. The files' name:
Lang.en-US.resx, Lang.es-ES.resx

The whole error looks like this:

```
MissingManifestResourceException was unhandled by user code

Could not find any resources appropriate for the 
specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure 
"WebApplication6.App_GlobalResources.Lang.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into 
assembly "WebApplication6" at compile time, or that all the satellite 
assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."
```

Again, in C# the whole thing worked. This code is Placed in a function, which is called from the Load_Page form.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is it really called `WebApplication6`?

Comment: yes, because I only created it for testing purposes, in order to implement it later to the real project.

Comment: never mind... I thought it was a typo and that's why it couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours trying to figure out, I found a solution.
What I did was replace this string:

```
rm = New ResourceManager("WebApplication6.App_GlobalResources.Lang", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
```

With this one:

```
rm = New ResourceManager("WebApplication6.Lang", System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("WebApplication6"))
```

But removing "App_GlobalResources" from the original string also worked. So the other posible solution is:

```
rm = New ResourceManager("WebApplication6.Language", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
```

After replacing the string I just left everything else as it is in the main post. Now everything's working fine.